# Parallel.For loop freezes

Tags: c#, datatable, parallel-processing

I'm trying to add to a DataTable some information in Parallel but if the the loop is to long it freezes or just takes a lot of time, more time then an usual for loop, this is my code for the Parallel.For loop:

```
Parallel.For(1, linii.Length, index =>
                 {
                     DataRow drRow = dtResult.NewRow();
                     alResult = CSVParser(linii[index], txtDelimiter, txtQualifier);

                     for (int i = 0; i < alResult.Count; i++)
                     {
                         drRow[i] = alResult[i];
                     }
                     dtResult.Rows.Add(drRow);
                 }
             );
```

What's wrong? this Parallel.For loop takes much more time than a normal one, what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to lock the data table. Adding rows is not thread safe

Comment: so I need first to lock the DataTable, then add a row to it ?

Comment: why do you need it parallel in the first place.

Comment: Yes, every time you do something to shared memory you need to lock it.

Comment: I need to do it in parallel because it's faster and I'm dealing with huge files

Comment: @XandrUu if you are dealing with huge files, your biggest problem is not the `Parallel` - it is the `linii[index]`. Loading all the lines at once is a **killer** for performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mutate a `DataTable` from 2 different threads; it **will** error. `DataTable` makes *no attempt* to be thread-safe. So: don't do that. Just do this from one thread. Most likely you are limited by IO, so you should just do it on a single thread as a stream. It looks like you're processing text data. You seem to have a `string[]` for lines, perhaps `File.ReadAllLines()` ? Well, that is very bad here:

1. it forces it all to load into memory
2. you have to *wait* for it all to load into memory
3. CSV is a multi-line format; it is not guaranteed that 1 line == 1 row

What you *should* do is use something like the CsvReader from code project, but even if you want to just use one line at a time, use a StreamReader:

```
using(var file = File.OpenText(path)) {
    string line;
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
        // process this line
        alResult = CSVParser(line, txtDelimiter, txtQualifier);

        for (int i = 0; i < alResult.Count; i++)
        {
            drRow[i] = alResult[i];
        }
        dtResult.Rows.Add(drRow);
    }
}
```

This will ***not*** be faster using `Parallel`, so I have not attempted to do so. IO is  your bottleneck here. Locking would be an option, but it isn't going to help you massively.

As an unrelated aside, I notice that `alResult` is not declared inside the loop. That means that in your original code `alResult` is a *captured variable* that is shared between ***all*** the loop iterations - which means you are already overwriting each row horribly.

---

Edit: illustration of why `Parallel` is not relevant for reading 1,000,000 lines from a file:

Approach 1: use `ReadAllLines` to load the lines, then use `Parallel` to process them; this costs [fixed time] for the physical file IO, and **then** we parallelise. The CPU work is minimal, and we've basically spent [fixed time]. However, we've added a lot of threading overhead and memory overhead, and we couldn't even **start** until all the file was loaded.

Approach 2: use a streaming API; read each one line by line - processing each line and adding it. The cost here is basically again: [fixed time] for the actual IO bandwidth to load the file. But; we now have no threading overhead, no sync conflicts, no huge memory to allocate, and we start filling the table *right away*.

Approach 3: If you *really* wanted, a third approach would be a reader/writer queue,  with one dedicated thread processing file IO and enqueueing the lines, and a second that does the `DataTable`. Frankly, it is a lot more moving parts, and the second thread will spend 95% of its time waiting for data from the file; stick to Approach 2!

Comment: but if i have an text that has 1 000 000 lines i have to wait for all to load, I can do it in Parallel.

Comment: Approach 2 was my first methode but I thought that it can be done faster, thanks a lot.

Comment: @XandrUu you can't do it faster than the bandwidth-time it takes to do the IO.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks a lot :) can you give my a contact of sort like an IM contact, if I have some more questions like this, I liked a lot the detailed explications..

Comment: @XandrUu You should ask another question on SO if you have another problem.  That's the purpose of the site after all.

Answer (score 1):

```
Parallel.For(1, linii.Length, index =>
{
  alResult = CSVParser(linii[index], txtDelimiter, txtQualifier);

  lock (dtResult)
  {
    DataRow drRow = dtResult.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < alResult.Count; i++)
    {
       drRow[i] = alResult[i];
    }
    dtResult.Rows.Add(drRow);
  }
});
```

Comment: One side-effect of this is that it randomises the row order. Not sure that is avoidable if the OP wants to use `Parallel`, though.

Comment: You can use a shared index, increment it with `Interlocked`, put all items in a `ConcurrentBag` with the index, sort and then insert to the datatable (after thread have finished)